# The logic schematic which can change the duty cycle of input

Tags: digital-logic, duty-cycle, square

Is there a logic schematic can change the duty cycle of input ? I mean if input is a square wave with duty cycle is equal to 50%,and the output is also a square wave but its duty cycle become lower or higher.

I have found 555-timer,but it's too hard for me.so I still have no idea with it,i want to find a easier way to make it.can anyone give me some suggestion?

Comment: If a simple 555 is too hard for you I am afraid there is nothing easier...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a logic schematic can change the duty cycle of input ?

Try looking up what a monostable does. A 555 can be configured to perform this function also. If it is still too hard to comprehend you need to ask questions at a lower level or explain specifically what it is about 555s you don't understand.

Comment: THX,I'll check the monostable

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished by a monoflop.
E.g. 4528 contains two. You need just two external components: one (variable) resistor and one capacitor:

[image]
(image from [this datasheet](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/HEF4528B.pdf), p. 10)

The duty cycle of the output can be varied by varying the RC time constant.

Using the left circuit rising edges of input and output signal would coincide and the falling edge of the output signal would be variable.
Vice versa with the right circuit.

Comment: THX,I'll check the monoflop